# Bind user object to each article in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

here is in this example i fetch all `category` that has `articles`
and bind all articles to each `category` that belongs to like this

```
 $categories = Category::has('articles')->with('articles')->get();
```

result

```js
   [
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Technology",
    "created_at": "2019-09-22 16:58:24",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-22 16:58:24",
    "articles": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Programming",
    "created_at": "2019-09-22 21:01:39",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-22 22:36:17",
    "articles": [{
      "id": 10,
      "title": "Intro To JavaScript",
      "content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "image": "articles/OUMvOY17KaqfcfK10c16UAcGegXeESopRw1hlxl9.png",
      "user_id": 1,
      "category_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2019-09-22 22:35:10",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-22 22:35:10"
    }]
  }
]
```

what I need is to bind also the `user` object for each `article` how can I make it

Comment: You can bind like this ->with(['articles' => function($query){ $query->with('user')}])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```php
 $categories = Category::has('articles')->with('articles' => function($query) {
    $query->with('user');
})->get();
```

Hope it helps.